# Trying to update Python 3.9 giving errors

Tags: python, python-3.x, ubuntu-20.04

What I've done:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:deadsnakes/ppa
sudo apt update
sudo apt install python3.9
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.8 1
sudo update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/python3 python3 /usr/bin/python3.9 2

python --version
```

Now I have multiple errors and cannot start terminator or update. When I start mate terminal, I receive this error:

```
/usr/bin/screenfetch: /usr/bin/lsb_release : /usr/bin/python3 : mauvais interpréteur: Aucun fichier ou dossier de ce type
```

When I actualise with synaptic, I receive this error:

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success 'if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/ -a -e /usr/lib/cnf-update-db; then /usr/lib/cnf-update-db > /dev/null; fi'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

All these errors began with the installation of Python as I describe in the beginning.

Comment: It is not recommended to update the `python3` "alternative" to the new python version. Many system tool use this and they will be missing libraries install only for the system version of Python. Don't mess with the system Python!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that post : [Problem with sudo apt update in Ubuntu 18.04: Post-Invoke-Success if /usr/bin/test -w /var/lib/command-not-found/](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1041226/problem-with-sudo-apt-update-in-ubuntu-18-04-post-invoke-success-if-usr-bin-te)

and i find an answer by doing :

```
apt download python3-minimal
sudo apt install --reinstall ./python3-minimal_*.deb
sudo apt install -f
```

I had to reinstall some few apps after that few lines and all is back to normal.